# How do I share two monitors, one mouse, and one keyboard between one Mac and two PCs?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, multiple-computers

I have the following machines that I would like to share two monitors:

- A Macbook Pro with two thunderbolt display ports
- A Windows PC for work with one HDMI and one VGA port
- A Windows gaming PC with two DVI ports

Each of my monitors have 1 DVI port, and 1 VGA port. Am willing to buy new ones since they need to be upgraded anyway.

What option do I have to share both monitors + keyboard + mouse between all three computers?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a special device called a KVM (keyboard-video-mouse) switch that will let you share them among your three computers. Dual video ports will get expensive. Here is an example of a KVM switch although it's not a dual-monitor one: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817707132

Some video delay can be added by the switch so be sure to look into that if you plan on gaming through it.